# Sencha Touch: Reload local store without list panel flashing loading screen

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, jsonstore

My customer has asked that a list panel that has been bound to a jsonstore be continuously updated so the data is live

I've added

```
activate: function() {
    app.subapps.freePc.controller.refreshInterval = window.setInterval("app.subapps.freePc.controller.refreshData()", 5000);
    app.subapps.freePc.controller.refreshData();
},
deactivate: function() {
    window.clearInterval(app.subapps.freePc.controller.refreshInterval);
}
```

(where app.subapps.freePc.controller.refreshData() calls read() on the store in question)

to my panel so that when it's activated it starts polling the server every 5 seconds for new data and stops when the view is no longer active

Functionally this works fine, the list is automatically redrawn and everything but every time it updates the list is removed, a loading screen is displayed and then the list is redrawn, which is really jolting and distracting for users

Is there anyway around this

Answer (score 0):

Via http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?173916-Reload-local-store-without-list-panel-flashing-loading-screen&p=713748&posted=1#post713748

> If you have loadingText = false it shouldn't show the loading mask. I would have some way for the user to know a reload is happening like a loading spinner in a toolbar or something.